# program cannot find libQt3Support.so.4

Tags: 11.10, qt

I am trying to run a program but the program complains that `error while loading shared libraries: libQt3Support.so.4: cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory`

I can see that the rest of the needed Qt libraries are there, only this one is not found. 
I did `find / -name libQt3Support.so.4` but this didnt return anything... most likely it is missing.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of that one. This is a missing library, not a missing repository. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: It appears this has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21744542/packet-tracer-libraries-needed-debian

Comment: 11.10 has long been end of life and no longer supported.  By continuing to run it you have been exposing yourself to unpatched security vulnerabilities so you need to upgrade at once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install the `libqt4-qt3support` package, which provides that library.

Comment: thank you. Where do I find his package? apt-get?

Comment: Yes. You can just apt-get install it.

Comment: didnt work from apt-get install, "failed to fetch ...", I think my version of linux is old and probably not supported...any other option to get this package?